# Unable to link CURL library

Tags: c, curl, makefile, libcurl

I am writing a C application using libcurl. I downloaded the libcurl from this link: http://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=lib&os=Win32&flav=-

I can compile and run the code when I set the path for header and library files in codeblocks. In codeblocks I gave the library path with library `libcurldll.a` I have kept `libcurl.a`, `libcurl.dll` and `libcurldll.a` in my executable forder. But when I write a makefile for this and give the path, then the code is not linking to curl libraries.  I get the message `undefined reference to _imp__curl_global_init` and so on for all curl functions in code.
Following is my makefile for the code:

```
OBJS =      http.o web_request.o
TARGET =    http

INC_PATH =  ./include
LIB_PATH=   ./libs

CC = gcc
os = windows

CFLAGS =    -c -g -I$(INC_PATH)
LDFLAGS =   -L$(LIB_PATH)

LIBS =   -lpthreadVC2 -lws2_32  -lcurl

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CC)  -o $(TARGET)  $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

http.o: http.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) http.c

web_request.o: web_request.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) web_request.c

clean:
    rm $(TARGET) $(OBJS)
```

Can anyone please tell what is wrong here? Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: where/what path did you place all your libraries?   It seems unlikely that all your libraries are in a directory below where your source code is located.   A similar question for the system include files?

Comment: The .exe file path is `C:\Users\Libcurl\testing _libcurl`   include path is : `C:\Users\Libcurl\testing _libcurl\bin` and library path `C:\Users\Libcurl\testing _libcurl\libs`

Comment: This doesn't make sense in relation to your makefile.
Your need to describe the project directory structure accurately,
*in the question* (not in comments), and say where the source
files, header files, libraries and makefile are in this structure.

Comment: strongly suggest removing the spaces from the directory names as that will be a problem in the makefile